# Swift compiler fails with segmentation when using extensions for protocol with associated type

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

This code fails:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype E : Decodable
    func u()
}

extension A {
    func u() {}
}

class E<T : Decodable> : A {
    typealias E = T
}
```

With error:

`1. While emitting IR SIL function "@$s12sddssddsdsds1ECyqd__GAA1AA2aEP1uyyFTW".
 for 'u()' (at /Users/semyontykhonenko/Library/Autosave Information/sddssddsdsds/sddssddsdsds/ViewController.swift:108:5)
0  swift                    0x0000000106dc0eb3 PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 51
1  swift                    0x0000000106dc0686 SignalHandler(int) + 358
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff67514b5d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 2561586368
4  swift                    0x0000000102a855b1 swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::searchWitnessTable(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::ProtocolDecl*, unsigned int, swift::irgen::MetadataPath&&, swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::InterestingKeysCallback const&, llvm::SmallPtrSetImpl<swift::ProtocolDecl*>*) + 65
5  swift                    0x0000000102a85522 swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::searchWitnessTable(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::ProtocolDecl*, unsigned int, swift::irgen::MetadataPath&&, swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::InterestingKeysCallback const&) + 450
6  swift                    0x0000000102a85328 void llvm::function_ref<void (unsigned int, swift::CanType, llvm::Optional<swift::ProtocolConformanceRef>)>::callback_fn<swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::searchNominalTypeMetadata(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::MetadataState, unsigned int, swift::irgen::MetadataPath&&, swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::InterestingKeysCallback const&)::$_1>(long, unsigned int, swift::CanType, llvm::Optional<swift::ProtocolConformanceRef>) + 1656
7  swift                    0x0000000102be644f swift::irgen::GenericTypeRequirements::enumerateFulfillments(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::SubstitutionMap, llvm::function_ref<void (unsigned int, swift::CanType, llvm::Optional<swift::ProtocolConformanceRef>)>) + 335
8  swift                    0x0000000102a844ee swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::searchNominalTypeMetadata(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::MetadataState, unsigned int, swift::irgen::MetadataPath&&, swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::InterestingKeysCallback const&) + 478
9  swift                    0x0000000102a842d0 swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::searchTypeMetadata(swift::irgen::IRGenModule&, swift::CanType, swift::irgen::IsExact_t, swift::MetadataState, unsigned int, swift::irgen::MetadataPath&&, swift::irgen::FulfillmentMap::InterestingKeysCallback const&) + 912
10 swift                    0x0000000102c9738d swift::irgen::IRGenFunction::bindLocalTypeDataFromTypeMetadata(swift::CanType, swift::irgen::IsExact_t, llvm::Value*, swift::MetadataState) + 317
11 swift                    0x0000000102be43a4 swift::irgen::emitPolymorphicParameters(swift::irgen::IRGenFunction&, swift::SILFunction&, swift::irgen::Explosion&, swift::irgen::WitnessMetadata*, llvm::function_ref<llvm::Value* (unsigned int)> const&) + 596
12 swift                    0x0000000102c4e355 swift::irgen::IRGenModule::emitSILFunction(swift::SILFunction*) + 6325
13 swift                    0x0000000102afe517 swift::irgen::IRGenerator::emitLazyDefinitions() + 9303
14 swift                    0x0000000102c2bf20 performIRGeneration(swift::IRGenOptions&, swift::ModuleDecl*, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::StringRef, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, llvm::LLVMContext&, swift::SourceFile*, llvm::GlobalVariable**) + 1344
15 swift                    0x0000000102a185aa performCompile(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation&, llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*, swift::UnifiedStatsReporter*) + 36682
16 swift                    0x0000000102a0be54 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6820
17 swift                    0x00000001029993c3 main + 1219
18 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6732f3d5 start + 1
19 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000049 start + 2563574901
error: Segmentation fault: 11 (in target 'sddssddsdsds' from project 'sddssddsdsds')`

If I remove Decodable from protocol requirement or add implementation of `u` to E it compiles successfully. So these variants are compiled successfully:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype E
    func u()
}

extension A {
    func u() {}
}

class E<T> : A {
    typealias E = T
}
```

And this one:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype E : Decodable
    func u()
}

extension A {
    func u() {}
}

class E<T : Decodable> : A {
    typealias E = T
    func u() {}
}
```

Version of XCode I am using: Version 11.1 (11A1027)
I tried Swift 5 and Swift 4.2. It fails with both

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault that's almost certainly a compiler bug, so you should raise a bug at [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org). You should also clarify which Swift version you're using and how you're compiling your code (from Xcode in a project/playground, command line, etc.).

Comment: Also, if you will use `E` in your `func u` declaration (or in any function/property declaration of protocol) it will compile.

Comment: Compiles fine in Xcode 13.3 (Swift 5.6), seems the bug was fixed.